# Extracting large tar.bz2 folders in parallel

Tags: performance, bash, concurrency, compression

The `bash` below utilizes parallel to extract `tar.bz2` folders with 9 files in them. The total size of each is around 60GB. Below are some specs of my system. My question is the below the best/fastest (currently takes ~ 1 hour) way to extract these large `tar.bz2` folders? I do not want to slow my system down or damage it so I wanted to ask more knowledgable users.

- OS = Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit
- Memory = 128 GB
- Processor = Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz × 16

```
#!/bin/bash

# parallel untar of tar.bz2

maxproc=3 # Max number of threads.
i=0

# Count files
set -- /path/to/folders/*.tar.bz2
FILES="$#"

# Blank $1 $2 ...
set --

let i=1
for FILE in /path/to/folders/*.tar.bz2
do
    printf "(%2d/%2d)\tProcessing %s\n" "$i" "$FILES" "$FILE"
    let i=i+1

    tar -xvjf "$FILE" -C /path/to/folders >/dev/null &

    # Turn $1=pida $2=pidb $3=pidc $4=pidd, into
    #      $1=pida $2=pidb $3=pidc $4=pidd $5=pide
    set -- "$@" $!

    # Shift removes $1 and moves the rest down, so you get
    # $1=pidb $2=pidc $3=pidd $3=pide
    # $# is the number of arguments.
    if [ "$#" -ge $maxproc ]  ; then wait "$1" ; shift; fi
done

wait
```

Comment: The system specification that is most likely to affect performance for this task is the storage. Are you writing to a local filesystem? Do you have SSDs? RAID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-purposing the argument list this way is not idiomatic Bash, and it took me some time to realise that (firstly) the supplied arguments are ignored and replaced with a list from filesystem and that (secondly) those arguments are replaced with the process IDs of the child `tar` processes.  It might be better to use distinctly-named array variables instead.

---

There's very little point in passing the `-v` argument to `tar` and then redirecting it to `/dev/null`.  If you don't pass `-v`, then `tar` will quietly get on with its job:

```
    tar -xjf "$FILE" -C /path/to/folders &
```

---

Why is `maxproc` set to `3`?  Is that an empirical value based on your observed disk (and filesystem) throughput?  If so, provide a means to overwrite it (e.g. allow it to be passed as an environment variable).

If you want to spawn one child for each processor (core) on your system, you might choose `maxproc=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)`; I'll leave it as an exercise to think of other possible defaults.

---

The `wait` command here waits for *a specific process* to exit.  If job 2 finishes before job 1, then the script won't start a new process to replace it until after job 1 completes, resulting in lower overall utilisation, especially if the jobs are of unequal size or proceeding at unequal rates.

Instead, replacing `wait "$1"` with `wait -n` will wait for *any one child process* to exit.  This is more likely to be what we want.

---

The script always returns a success value, even if one or more extractions fail (e.g. due to a full filesystem).  It's possible to remember that an error occurred:

```
status=0
for FILE in ...
do
    ...
    wait -n || status=1
done

wait || status=1
exit $status
```

---

Consider using an existing implementation of `parallel` or `xjobs` rather than reinventing the wheel.  That turns this script into a simple one-liner.

Comment: `maxproc` is set to 3 because I did not want to slow my system down to a halt, but that is more me not knowing. I also tried 2 and saw little difference. What do you suggest.  Thank you :).

Comment: I've edited to show how you can adapt to the number of available processors.  If you need to reserve a couple of cores for other tasks, you could do the appropriate arithmetic, but I'd suggest going with one-per-core until proven otherwise.  Disk I/O is more likely to be the bottleneck than CPU or RAM.